# bootstrap popover to dynamically created anchor in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, popover

I am trying to tie an popover to dynamically created anchor in jQuery datatable. But it is not working I have already explored couple of threads here but not able to follow properly. Below is my code.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* reference verse popup */
    $('#bibletext').on('click','a#btnrefpop',showrefpop);
});
```

Below is the funciton I have bound on a click event of an anchor dynamically created in datatable

```
function showrefpop(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var refverse = e.currentTarget.innerText;
    var passage = getPassage(refverse);
    var refelemid = '#'+e.currentTarget.id;
    if (passage != undefined)
    {
         dbservice.fetch(bibleConfig.geturl,passage)
        .done(function(res){
            $(refelemid).popover({
                 html:true,
                 container : 'body',
                 content: function(){ return 
                            $('#verserefpopover').html(res.versetext); 
                    }
            });
          })
         .fail(function(err){
             siteConfig.log(err);
          });
    }
}
```

**HTML**

Below is the popover content div in my HTML

```
<div id="verserefpopover" class="hide-menu"></div>
```

Below is the anchor which is created for each datatable row

```
"<a hef='' id='btnrefpop' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='right' data-html='true' class='refspan'>"+vrefs[i]+"</a>"
```

Events are fired as expected and data is also fetched and populated in popover DIV but the popup is never shown.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating dynamic popovers you need to delegate them.

Try:

```
$( function () {
    /* delegate popover */
    $( document ).popover( {
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click', // click, hover, focus
        selector: '.refspan[data-toggle="popover"]',
        container: 'body'
    } );

    /* reference verse popup */
    $( '#bibletext' ).on( 'click', '.refspan[data-toggle="popover"]', showrefpop );
} );

function showrefpop( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var self = this;
    var refverse = self.innerText;
    var passage = getPassage( refverse );
    if ( passage != undefined ) {
        dbservice.fetch( bibleConfig.geturl, passage ).done( function ( res ) {
            var verserefpopover = $( '#verserefpopover' );
            verserefpopover.html( $.parseHTML( res.versetext ) );

            var jqueryEl = $( self );
            jqueryEl.attr( 'data-content', verserefpopover.html() );
            jqueryEl.popover( 'hide' );
            jqueryEl.popover( 'show' );
        } ).fail( function ( err ) {
            siteConfig.log( err );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zavarock....I understood the lack of delegation and got it working. However the popover content is not changing as I click on different anchors. It remains static as "Loading....".

Comment: My apologies.....my json format was causing the issue. All well now!!! Thank you so much for your help Zavarock. Really appreciated.

Comment: @SherebyahTishbi Good to know. If my answer solved your problem, I appreciate if you mark it as accepted.

Comment: yes I just marked your answer as accepted. All working so nice and smooth! Excellent solution!

Comment: Just realized one issue here. It takes 2 clicks to show the dynamic content. On first click it shows "Loading..." and on the 2nd click it shows the actual dynamic content.

Comment: @SherebyahTishbi I just edited my answer, could you try it again? By the way, is a good idea use $.parseHTML for security reasons.

Comment: :) now the content shows on first click but popup is always visible...it does not toggle.

Comment: Try change `trigger: 'click'` to **focus** or **hover**. If you put your script online I can try improve it.